# Acts_as_votable does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have installed 'acts_as_votable' gem, but id doesn't work.
Here is what I get:

```
undefined method `like_answer_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f882266a948>:0x007f8824a012d0>
```

**My routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  resources :questions do
    resources :answers do
      member do
        put "like", to: "answers#upvote"
      end
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

**answers_controller.rb:**

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def upvote
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    @answer.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to question_path(@question)
  end
  ...
end
```

**_answer.html.slim**

```
.answer id="answer-#{answer.id}"
  .contents= answer.contents
  .details
    '  Answered on
    = l(answer.created_at, format: :long)
    '  by
    = link_to answer.user, user_path(answer.user)
    = link_to "upvote", like_answer_path(@answer), method: :put
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `like_answer_path' for Class:0x007f882266a948

When you run `rake routes`, you get

```
like_question_answer PUT  /questions/:question_id/answers/:id/like(.:format)                        answers#upvote
```

So your `link_to` should be

```
= link_to "upvote", like_question_answer_path(@question,@answer), method: :put
```